# Вектор с динамическим типом

Tags: c++, vector

Появилась такая задача:

```
    struct A{
    int a;
int b;
char a[256];
};
struct B:public A{
int a;
int t;
char p[256];
};
//есть два класса, у родительского есть виртуальная функция:
class A1{
virtual void test(std::vector<A>*vec){


}

};
class B1:public A1{

void test(std::vector<A>*vec) override {


}

}
```

Я хочу в классе B1 передавать в функцию вектор с типом B1, а в функцию класса A1 вектор с типом A. Как это реализовать? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Если аргументы функций будут разными, то функция в классе B1 не сможет делать override виртуальной функции в базовом классе.

Comment: std::vector (как и большинство подобных плюсовых типов) не поддерживают ковариантность. Поэтому, это нельзя сделать так как Вы написали. Но если сигнатуру можно трогать, то как всегда, есть варианты.

Comment: @KoVadim , например? Я думал использовать std::vector<std::variant<A,B>>, но что-то не срослось. Возможно, я не правильно понял принцип работы std::variant

Comment: @user7860670 была мысль обращаться к вектору через указатель

Comment: @user7860670 ,В примере ошибся. Звёздочка должна быть в скобках

Comment: `std::vector<std::variant<A,B>>` должен был бы прокатить, так как типы функций получились бы одинаковыми. А с указателем это была нездоровая затея. 'В примере ошибся" - вопросы можно править.

Comment: @user7860670 , у меня конкретно не получилось его заполнить. Можешь привести,пожалуйста, пример заполнения вектора с вариантом?

Comment: @Sokol - тут нужно саму задачу глубже смотреть, может она плохо декомпозирована. Но можно сделать объект-прокси и вот через него уже можно будет сделать желаемое.